# How to hide a custom text attribute which displayed in product edit backend

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, custom-options, uicomponent, custom-attributes

I am using Magento 2.2.5

I need to hide **a text attribute** which I'm using to save **serialized** data of custom options of product.

[image: Edit Product in magento backend]

I think this can be done using `adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml` file, but don't know how.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below steps to hide product fields

**Step 1:**

create **catalog_product_edit.xml** under ***app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout***

File : **catalog_product_edit.xml**

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="myattribHide" before="before.body.end" template="Vendor_Module::product/edit/fieldhide.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

**Step 2:** 
Create file **fieldhide.phtml** under ***app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/product/edit***

File : ***fieldhide.phtml***

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'uiRegistry'
    ], function($,uiRegistry){
        uiRegistry.get("product_form.product_form.content.container_yourcustomfield.yourcustomfield", function (element) {
         element.hide();
      });        
    })
</script>
```

*Note :* Please replace "yourcustomfield" with your attribute code

**Step 3:**
Please remove static files and refresh cache

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try this and update you regarding its result.

Comment: I have tried your way but unable to have the desired result, I have done and cleared cache like 
**rm -rf pub/static/* var/di/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/* var/view_preprocessed/* && php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:upgrade && php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f**

Comment: can you please confirm JS is working or not . Also make sure you replace yourcustomfield.yourcustomfield with your field id. For that please right click and use View Source tool of your browser.

Comment: I have checked the file does not called at all. I have add console.log() after first line of script tag.

Comment: How can i remove a custom field in account informaion in admin area?

Answer (score 0):

I have added below line in my install script to not display the attribute in product edit page in admin.

> $installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product', $attribute_code, 'is_visible', '0');

I have found the [Hide Attributes and Other Fields in Product Edit Backend](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3603/hide-attributes-and-other-fields-in-product-edit-backend)
reference from an older question.

> CAUTION :: With this approach, I'm **not able to display saved serialized data in fields.**

This question is related with my other question in which I have mentioned how to save product's custom options in serialized form in attribute [How to save serialized data in product's text backend_type custom attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252790/how-to-save-serilized-data-in-products-text-backend-type-custom-attribute).